# Plotting curve in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am given the coordinates of the center of mass of a particle $(x_G,y_G)$ with respect to time $t$, I want to plot a graph the shows the change in the position of the particle with respect to time.
The first variable is the time $t$, I have thought about taking the second variable to be $\sqrt{x_G^2 + y_G^2}$.

Is this a good idea? Or how can we detect the position better?

Comment: If you want to plot the position you should plot the points $(x_G(t), y_G(t))$, which give you the position of the center of mass of the particle for each $t$.

Comment: @Javi. Can I plot a curve considering 3 variables?

Comment: It's actually one if $x$ and $y$ ar functions of $t$. The trajectory is supposed to be a curve